# How does the OAuth workflow fit in when using Stripe Connect managed accounts?

Tags: oauth, stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.net

I am developing a Web application that will charge a percentage fee of the transaction between two consenting parties who want to do business.

My question is -- do I need the OAuth registration, `client Id` and `client secret` if I am going to use managed accounts?

I have read the OAuth 1.0a and 2.0 specifications and am intimately aware of its implementation. My question simply is -- *do I need it?*

Esp. when I am not creating a native mobile app but a web application where I will be getting tokens (Stripe tokens and not OAuth access tokens) using `Stripe.js` where needed and then the actual charge or transaction I will make from my ASP.NET server to the Stripe server.

I see that there are two ways of authentication -- one uses the `Stripe-Account` HTTP header with the Stripe secret key and the other uses the OAuth access token. This means that getting an access token is not mandatory.

If I don't *absolutely need* an access token (as I observe from most API calls in the documentation) to make charges and transfers on behalf of connected managed accounts, then why do I need to register with a client Id and client secret and where does the initial OAuth *handshake / user consent / authorization* workflow fit in when creating managed accounts?

If I do go the OAuth route, do I first create a managed account for the user and then initiate OAuth workflow, i.e. take him to the "consent dialog?" Or do I first ask for his consent and then create the managed account for him?

If I don't need the initial handshake, then how and where am I getting the user's consent that I am acting on his behalf?

What is this workflow going to be like other than showing him a "Please accept these terms of service and these Stripe Connect Agreement."

Comment: Oauth doesn't play a roll with managed accounts

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewArkin. Just what I suspected but the documentation is confusing. Just trying out what you said.